# Flutter: How to convert Path String to File in Flutter Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, file, path, file-conversion

I am trying to implement a voice message feature in Flutter for my ***Chat Application**.* Therefore, to **record the audio**, I am using ***Record 4.4.4 Flutter Package.***

Everything is working fine from recording to playing it locally (as a preview) in my Audio Player ***voice_message_package**.* But ***the problem strikes*** when it comes to
***Converting the file Path into Path*** to store in Firebase Storage.

this is the error:

> 'package:firebase_storage/src/reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 127 pos 12: 'file.absolute.existsSync()': is not true.

*These are the codes :*

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:example/exampleThemeManagement/ThemeManagement.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';
import 'package:voice_message_package/voice_message_package.dart';

class AudioRecorder extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioRecorder({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioRecorder> createState() => _AudioRecorderState();
}

class _AudioRecorderState extends State<AudioRecorder> {

  /// --------------- Variables ----------------- ///

  final record = Record();
  final _audioRecorder = Record();
  bool isRecording = false;
  int _recordDuration = 0;
  Timer? _timer;
  RecordState _recordState = RecordState.stop;
  bool _isRecordingMessage = false;
  bool _isPaused = false;
  String _voiceMessagePath = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _audioRecorder.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// ------------ Start Recording and End Recording Functions  ------------ //

  Future<void> _start() async {
    try {
      if (await _audioRecorder.hasPermission()) {
        await _audioRecorder.start();
        _recordDuration = 0;

        _startTimer();
        isRecording = await record.isRecording();

        setState(() {});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stop() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _recordDuration = 0;

    final path = await _audioRecorder.stop();

    // if (path != null) {
    //   widget.onStop(path);
    // }
    setState(() {
      _voiceMessagePath = path.toString();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Recorder"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            isRecording ?
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  /// ------------ Cancel Voice Message ----------- //
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      // -------- Deleting Voice Message ---------- //
                      _stop();
                      setState(() {
                        isRecording = false;
                        _isPaused = false;
                        _isRecordingMessage = false;
                        _voiceMessagePath = "";
                      });
                    },
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 45,
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 24, color: hangoutTheme.green,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  /// ------------ Recording Voice Message ----------- //
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Container(
                    width: (size.width * 1) - 120,
                    height: 45,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000),
                      color: hangoutTheme.green,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        /// ---------- Play and Pause Widgets --------- //
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            if (!_isPaused) {
                              _pause();
                              print("Pause");
                              setState(() {
                                _isPaused = true;
                              });

                            } else {
                              _resume();
                              print("Resume");
                              setState(() {
                                _isPaused = false;
                              });

                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Icon(!_isPaused ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow, size: 24, color: Colors.white,),
                            ),
                            // child: _buildPauseResumeControl(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        /// ---------- Recording Visuals --------- //
                        Container(
                          width: (size.width * 1) - 180,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 30,
                                child: _buildTimer(),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: (size.width * 1) - 210,
                                height: 10,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                          color: int.parse(minutes1) >= 1 && int.parse(seconds1) > 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                          color: int.parse(minutes1) >= 2 && int.parse(seconds1) > 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                          color: int.parse(minutes1) >= 3 && int.parse(seconds1) > 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                          color: int.parse(minutes1) >= 4 && int.parse(seconds1) > 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  /// ------------ End Voice Message ----------- //
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      // -------- Deleting Voice Message ---------- //
                      await _stop();
                      setState(() {
                        isRecording = false;
                        _isPaused = false;
                        _isRecordingMessage = false;
                      });
                      print("Recording Sent : ${_voiceMessagePath}");
                    },
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 45,
                      child: Center(child: ImageIcon(AssetImage("HangoutIcon/paper-plane.png"), size: 24, color: hangoutTheme.green,),),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ) :
            /// ------------ Start Recording Voice Message ----------- //
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                _start();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 45,
                  width: 45,
                  child: Icon(Icons.mic, size: 24, color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),

            /// ------------ Show Preview of Recorded Voice Message ----------- //
            _voiceMessagePath.isNotEmpty ?
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // color: hangoutTheme.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              child: VoiceMessage(
                audioSrc: (_voiceMessagePath),
                played: false, // To show played badge or not.
                me: false, // Set message side.
                onPlay: () {}, // Do something when voice played.
                meBgColor: hangoutTheme.green,
                contactFgColor: hangoutTheme.green,
                contactPlayIconColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ) : Container(),

            /// ------------ Save to Database ----------- //
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                storeVoiceMessage(_voiceMessagePath);
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("Send It!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),)
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  /// ------------ Other Functionalities and Widget for the Timer and Pause/Play  ------------ //

  Future<void> _pause() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    await _audioRecorder.pause();
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  Future<void> _resume() async {
    _startTimer();
    await _audioRecorder.resume();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _buildPauseResumeControl() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
        if (_recordState == RecordState.pause) {
          _resume();
          setState(() {});
        } else {
          _pause();
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(isRecording ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow, size: 24, color: Colors.white,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String minutes1 = "";
  String seconds1 = "";

  Widget _buildTimer() {
    final String minutes = _formatNumber(_recordDuration ~/ 60);
    final String seconds = _formatNumber(_recordDuration % 60);

    if(minutes.isNotEmpty && seconds.isNotEmpty) {
      minutes1 = minutes;
      seconds1 = seconds;
    }

    if(int.parse(minutes) >= 5) {
      _stop();
    }

    return Center(
      child: Text("$minutes : $seconds | Recording...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white,),),
    );
  }

  String _formatNumber(int number) {
    String numberStr = number.toString();
    if (number < 10) {
      numberStr = '0$numberStr';
    }

    return numberStr;
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();

    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      setState(() => _recordDuration++);
    });
  }


  /// ------------- Uploading Audio Message to Firebase ------------ ///
  Future storeVoiceMessage(var file) async {

    File _newfile = await File(file);

    final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    var snapshot = await storage.ref().child("Hangout/Tester").putFile(_newfile);
    String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    print("Downloaded URL : " + url);


    return url;
  }
}
```

Main Areas

Ending Voice Message and Storing Locally (Saved Automatically by the packages) (set 1)

```
Future<void> _stop() async {
  _timer?.cancel();
  _recordDuration = 0;

  final path = await _audioRecorder.stop();

  /// ---------- Below (Getting file Path) ---------- //
  setState(() {
    _voiceMessagePath = path.toString();
  });
}
```

Locally Displaying the file (set 2)

```
VoiceMessage(
  audioSrc: (_voiceMessagePath),
  played: false, // To show played badge or not.
  me: false, // Set message side.
  onPlay: () {}, // Do something when voice played.
  meBgColor: Colors.purple,
  contactBgColor: Colors.red,
  contactFgColor: Colors.green,
  contactPlayIconColor: Colors.white,
),
```

Saving to Database Codes (set 3)

```
Future storeVoiceMessage(var file) async {

  File _newfile = await File(file);

  final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  var snapshot = await storage.ref().child("Hangout/Tester").putFile(_newfile);
  String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  print("Downloaded URL : " + url);


  return url;
}
```

Comment: If you want to store the file path then you should upload audio file to firebase storage and get the file path as string to manipulate

Comment: Dude, I am unable to store it to Firebase storage because when I try to upload it by first converting String Path to File `File file = File(_path)`, it shows an error: something that the file doesn't exist. I do get the Path, but it's not getting converted to file to being eligible to be stored to firebase!

Comment: I don't see the `File file = File(_path)` line in the code you shared in the question, and find it hard to correlate the error message you get to the four blocks of code. Can you show a single block of code (preferably with no UI builder) that reproduces the error, and include the exact stack that you then get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `File file = File(_path)` is just an example, but the actual codes are  `File _newfile = await File(file);` *Saving to Database Codes (set 3).*